# Making form fields compulsory in form type

Tags: php, symfony

I want to add a validation so that the the **keyword** and the **field** form elements become compulsory. These are not attached to any kind of entity though. I'm just going to handle the request in my controller. I'm not interested in HTML5 validation which I can do it myself.

**Rules:** `Keyword` cannot be null and `Field` cannot have anything apart from *firstname* or *middlename* values.

**FORM TYPE:**

```
class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $field = array('' => '', 'firstname' => 'Firstname', 'middlename' => 'Middlename');

        $builder
                ->setAction($options['action'])
                ->setMethod('POST')
                ->add('keyword', 'text', array('label' => 'Keyword', 'error_bubbling' => true))
                ->add('field', 'choice', array('label' => 'Field', 'choices' => $field, 'error_bubbling' => true))
                ->add('search', 'submit', array('label' => 'Search'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'personsearch';
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new SearchType(), array(),
                array('action' => $this->generateUrl('searchDo')));

        return $this->render('SeHirBundle:Default:search.html.twig',
                array('page' => 'Search', 'form' => $form->createView()));
    }

    public function searchAction(Request $request)
    {
        //I'll carry out searching process here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page in the docs details how to do what you want: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

Specifically, with your implementation of forms you can do something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

// ...

$builder
    ->setAction($options['action'])
    ->setMethod('POST')
    ->add('keyword', 'text', array(
        'label'          => 'Keyword', 
        'error_bubbling' => true,
        'constraints'    => array(
            new NotBlank(),
        )
    ))
    ->add('field', 'choice', array(
        'label' => 'Field', 
        'choices' => $field, 
        'error_bubbling' => true
    ))
    ->add('search', 'submit', array(
        'label' => 'Search'
    ))
;
```

More on this at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class

As for your `field` element, you may need to make a new constraint yourself for that.

---

You may also like to look at the "Validation and Forms" section. Personally I prefer using the annotations method when doing validation.

If you want to use that method then, on your model, add the following use statement:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

And then use an annotation above the property you are validating:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
public $name;
```

---

All of the constraints available may be found and described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-constraints

From your code, it seems you're not checking if the form is valid, you can add this section, and then redirect to your search action when the model is deemed valid.

Comment: I prefer annotations too. I only used annotations within db Entity class with Doctrine so far and I didn't know we could use a model just for validation (with annotations) purposes without attaching the form to any database! Good that you mentioned models. I'll read up on it now. I'm new so I have a lot to learn.

Comment: The validation component is actually really cool, you can make any old class and validate properties on them. And it's really easy to do that outside of forms too.